# Nginx detects the request's IP incorrectly from some users

Tags: nginx, nginx-config, nginx-location

When checking the access log of Nginx, I see that the IP of my friend's device is detected incorrectly. But Nginx still detects my IP correctly even when I try to change the other network.

For example, my friend's IP is x.x.69.209 (checked on https://www.whatismyip.com/), but in the access log, the IP that was logged is x.x.69.210. She also tried to change the other network. But still met the same problem. She tested with Chrome on MacOS, and Safari on iOS. She didn't use proxy, VPN.

I asked another friend to access my site and his IP was detected correctly like me. So strange.

My site runs with CentOS 7, Nginx version is 1.20.1. My site is set up on an AWS EC2 instance.

I have some other sites that were set up on other EC2 instances with the same OS, Nginx version, and Nginx configuration. And there's one site that detects my friend's IP correctly.

Nginx config:

```
server {
  server_name <domain-of-my-site>;

  access_log   /var/log/nginx/default.access.log main;
  error_log   /var/log/nginx/default.error.log;

  proxy_buffer_size   128k;
  proxy_buffers   4 256k;
  proxy_busy_buffers_size   256k;
  client_max_body_size 100M;
  large_client_header_buffers 4 32k;

  location / {
    proxy_send_timeout   90;
    proxy_read_timeout   90;
    proxy_connect_timeout 30s;
    proxy_http_version      1.1;

    proxy_set_header        Host $host;
    proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header        Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header        Connection 'upgrade';

    proxy_pass      http://127.0.0.1:3000;
  }

  listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
  listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/<domain-of-my-site>/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/<domain-of-my-site>/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
  include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
  ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}

server {
  if ($host = <domain-of-my-site>) {
      return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
  } # managed by Certbot

  listen       80;
  listen       [::]:80;

  server_name  <domain-of-my-site>;
  return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

I tried to restart Nginx, tried to upgrade Nginx version to the latest version. But still met the same problem.

Comment: Your friends ip-address will always be correct. Otherwise the tcp-packets won't come back.

Comment: Do you mean that your friend's IP displayed correctly just for one site and the others are wrong, however, the wrong IP is still in the same range as the correct IP?